# Formula to determine amount before percentage deductions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For some reason, i'm having trouble working out what should be a rather simple algebraic formula.

I have amount (X), which is the amount added to an account after tax (T) and fees (F) are deducted from the original payment (P). I know the value of X, T and F and need to determine the value of P. The part i'm getting hung up on is that T and F are percentages of P (ie: T = 20%, F = 3%).

Example:

```
P = 100
T = .20
F = .03
X = 77

P - (P * (T + F)) = X
100 - (100 * (.20 + .03) = 77
```

How can I calculate P, if I only know T, F and X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original equation:
$$P-(P(T+F)) = X$$

Factoring P:
$$P\cdot [1-(T+F)] = X$$

Dividing both sides of the equation by $1-(T+F)$:
$$P = \frac{X}{1-(T+F)}$$

This should be clear enough, if you still don't understand something, feel free to ask!

Comment: Could you explain the rule behind the 'Factoring P' step. It's been a few years since I was in high school and I've clearly forgotten this.

Comment: Of course! The law behind that 'factorization' is what's known as the [distributive law](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/distributive-law.html#:~:text=The%20Distributive%20Law%20says%20that,as%20doing%20each%20multiplication%20separately.), which simply states that for any 2 numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$, the following is true: $c(a+b) = ca + cb$.

Comment: Hey @David, if my answer has been helpful, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

The terms $P$ and $P\times(T+F)$ have a common factor of $P$.

Use distribution of multiplication over addition to get a single factor $P$:

$$  xa + xb = x(a+b).$$

Comment: lol, damn I forgot all about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Adding T and P together we get that they take out $23\%$ of P
$$P-0.23P=0.77P=X\implies P=\frac{X}{0.77}\approx (1.298701299)X$$
so $$P\approx X\times 130\%$$